# Pandas error : can only use .str accessor with string values which use no.object dtype

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

My input file is a Json file

```
{ "infile":"c:/tmp/cust-in-sample.xlsx",
   "SheetName":"Sheet1",
   "CleanColumns":[1,2],
   "DeleteColumns":[3,5],
   "outfile":"c:/tmp/out-cust-in-sample.csv"            
}
```

I would like to have specified columns in json to cleaned and deleted. However I'm getting the pandas string error.

I'm currently trying this code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import shutil
import sys

zJsonFile = sys.argv[-1]

iCount = len(sys.argv)


if iCount == 2:
    print "json file path " ,zJsonFile
else:
    print "need a json file path ending the script"
    sys.exit()


with open(zJsonFile,'rb') as zTestJson:
    decoded = json.load(zTestJson)

#Parameterizing the code, reading each key from 'decoded' variable and putting it into another variable for the purpose 
#of parameterizing

Infile = decoded.get('infile')
print Infile


Outfile = decoded.get('outfile')
print Outfile


Sheetname = decoded.get('SheetName')
print Sheetname

# this is a list
deletecols = decoded.get('DeleteColumns')
print deletecols

#this is a list
cleancols = decoded.get('CleanColumns')
print cleancols
input_sheet = pd.ExcelFile(Infile)                            
dfs = {}                                                     
for x in [Sheetname]:                          
    dfs[x] = input_sheet.parse(x)
    print dfs                                             

df = pd.DataFrame(dfs[x])             # COnverting dict to dataframe
print df
deletecols = df.columns.values.tolist()
cleancols = df.columns.values.tolist()
for idx,item in enumerate(deletecols):
    df.pop(item)
#df.drop(df.columns[deletecols],axis=1,inplace=True)   
#Cleaning the code
#cleancols=[]
for x in cleancols:                                                                       
    df[x] = df[x].str.replace(to_replace = '"', value = '', regex = True)
    df[x] = df[x].str.replace(to_replace = "'", value = '', regex = True)
    df[x] = df[x].str.replace(to_replace = ",", value = '', regex = True)
```

I tried df.pop, df.drop nothing of this looks like its working for me and neither creating a loop and looping through cleancols is cleaning my file.

Any help is highly appreciated.!

Comment: Could you add the head of the `df` alongside?

Comment: The error is clear you're performing string operation on non string `dtype` columns, what does `df.info()` show? you need to perform the clean on string columns only